# Simple Scala coding question

Tags: scala

Suppose I have list `countries` of type `List[String]` and map `capitals` of type `Map[String, String]`. Now I would like to write a function

```
pairs(countries:List[String], capitals:Map[String, String]):Seq[(String, String)]
```

to return a sequence of pairs `(country, capital)` and print an error if the capital for some country is not found. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To start with, your `Map[String,String]` is *already* a `Seq[(String,String)]`, you can formalise this a bit by calling `toSeq` if you wish:

```
val xs = Map("UK" -> "London", "France" -> "Paris")
xs.toSeq
// yields a Seq[(String, String)]
```

So the problem then boils down to finding countries that aren't in the map.  You have two ways of getting a collection of those countries that *are* represented.

The `keys` method will return an `Iterator[String]`, whilst `keySet` will return a `Set[String]`.  Let's favour the latter:

```
val countriesWithCapitals = xs.keySet
val allCountries = List("France", "UK", "Italy")
val countriesWithoutCapitals = allCountries.toSet -- countriesWithCapitals
//yields Set("Italy")
```

Convert that into an error in whatever way you see fit.

Comment: Are you assuming that the list of countries is a superset of the keys of the map? The primary goal might be to present the capitals of a small list of countries, rather than to find missing countries in the Map. It's not completely clear from the question, though.

Comment: @Ben - I'm working from the description: "print a error if the capital for some country is not found"

Answer (score 9):

```
countries.map(x=>(x, capitals(x)))
```